# Audio Controller not working on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I just installed Linux Mint 17.2 (MATE) on laptop hp probook 450 g1. 
however i can't use Audio, it not working.

I try sudo inxi -Fxi

> System:    Host: skd-HP-ProBook-450-G1 Kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic
>   x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2)
>
> ```
>        Desktop: MATE 1.10.0  Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela Machine:   System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ProBook 450 G1 version:
> ```
>
> A3008CD10003 serial: 2CE35020CW
>
> ```
>        Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1942 version: KBC Version 89.10 serial: PDWTF1B2D5T9B0
> ```
>
> Bios: Hewlett-Packard version: L74 Ver. 01.05 date: 11/04/2013
>
> CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4000M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
>   flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9578.56
>
> Clock Speeds: 1: 2400.00 MHz 2: 2400.00 MHz 3: 2400.093 MHz 4: 2400.00
>   MHz
>
> Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
>   Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
>
> X.org: 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) tty size: 80x24
>   Advanced Data: N/A for root
>
> **Audio:     Card-1: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller bus-ID: 00:1b.0 
>              Card-2: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller bus-ID: 00:03.0**
>
> Network:   Card-1: MEDIATEK MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
>   driver: rt2800pci bus-ID: 03:00.0
>              IF: wlan0 state: down mac: fc:4d:d4:57:0c:72
>              Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169 port: 3000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
>              IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: a0:1d:48:a8:8e:6b
>              WAN IP: 14.161.19.153 IF: eth0 ip: 192.168.100.2 ip-v6: fe80::a21d:48ff:fea8:8e6b 
>              IF: wlan0 ip: N/A ip-v6: fe80::fe4d:d4ff:fe57:c72  Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (1.2% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST500LM000
>   size: 500.1GB temp: 41C  Partition: ID: / size: 14G used: 5.2G (40%)
>   fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 38G used: 473M (2%) fs: ext4 
>              ID: swap-1 size: 4.09GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap  RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module
>   present Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0C mobo: 0.0C 
>              Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A  Info:      Processes: 210 Uptime: 1:06 Memory: 1854.3/3834.0MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4
>   Client: Shell (sudo) inxi: 1.9.17

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify how you have tested the sound card. Does running `speaker-test` produce a sound?